# storing system time to a variable in cpp

Tags: c++, variables, time, system

I want to save the local time to a char variable. here is the code i have used. but it is saying

> "cannot convert char * to char"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tme
{
  char intime;
}e;
void main( )
{

  char timeStr [9];
 _strtime( timeStr );
  e.intime=timeStr;
  printf( "The current time is %s \n", timeStr);
 }
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Be informed that `_strtime` is a Windows function, rendering your code snippet non-standard-compliant. Kindly consider using `const time_t current = time( NULL ); strftime( timeStr, 9, "%H:%M:%S", localtime(&current) );`, even if it looks like a handful, because it makes your code not unnecessarily depending on a (deprecated) Windows-only function.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple, you have a char array `timeStr` of length `9` and trying to assign it to a `char intime`. There's type incompatibility. Think of it as `char[]` is never equal to `char`.

You could solve this as follows (but I don't know what you want to achieve):

```
struct tme
{
  char* intime;
}e;
```

*PS*: MSDN states that ([_strtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2besbye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

> // Note: _strtime is deprecated; consider using _strtime_s instead

Answer (score 0):

```
  e.intime=timeStr;
```

`timeStr` is of type `char [9]`. It decays to a pointer pointing to first element during assignments or in a function call used as a parameter.

`e.intime` is of type `char`. `char` and `char*` aren't type compatible and the compiler is complaining you that. Instead you can do -

```
struct tme
{
  char intime[10]; // +1 for the termination character to play safe
}e;
```

Now, strcpy can be used to copy the time to the member variable.

```
strcpy(e.intime, timeStr);
```

If it is C++, use **std::string** instead of raw arrays.

Comment: A buffer size of 9 suffices: six digits, two colons, and a null character.

Comment: If that extra termination character is required, then it is not safe (because timeStr won't have a terminating null, so strcpy might overwrite more than 10 chars). But in fact strTime is guaranteed to be null-terminated, so 9 characters are enough.

Comment: @TonyK - strcpy never overwrites just because it has some more left over space at destination. It just copies the source to destination until the source is hit by `\0`.

Comment: @Mahesh: I know what strcpy does! Your extra byte is superfluous because (i) if timeStr is zero-terminated, then it's not needed; and (ii) if timeStr is not zero-terminated, then it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Some stages of refinement:

Stage 1: Fix your code.

```
struct tme {
  char * intime; // You had a type mismatch
} e;

int main () { // Don't use void main()
  char timeStr [9];
 _strtime( timeStr );
  e.intime=timeStr;
  printf( "The current time is %s \n", timeStr);
}
```

There's a problem here: Your `struct tme` is relying on the external world to do everything for it, and to do so correctly. What if we want to reuse `timeStr` in main? What if you use this structure in a function other than `main` and set `e.intime` to a variable that goes out of scope?

Refinement: `struct tme` should own the time buffer.

```
struct tme {
  char intime[9]; // Put the buffer here, not in main.
} e;

int main () {
  _strtime( e.intime );
  printf( "The current time is %s \n", e.intime);
}
```

We still have a problem here. That buffer can be modified by anyone, and the structure is just a passive receptacle.

Refinement: Hide the data and make the object active.

```
struct tme {
  const char * set_time () { _strtime (intime); return intime; }
  const char * get_time () const { return intime; }
private:
  char intime[9];
};

int main () {
  printf( "The current time is %s \n", e.set_time());
}
```